# Incremented tools?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> Your precision improves with more finely **incremented** tools that require less estimation.

<sup>A line from [*What's the difference between accuracy and precision?* in YouTube](https://youtu.be/hRAFPdDppzs?t=1m48s).</sup>

As I've never seen *incremented something*, I assume it means *bettered* here. Exactly how is *incremented* used here, and is it used commonly?

Comment: It refers to the markings (or any sort of electronic equivalent).  A ruler with fine markings (ie, markings that are close together) is more precise.  The usage is a bit uncommon, but is readily understandable if you consider that each mark is an "increment".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An older term would be *divided*, and refers to the number of divisions (markings) on a scale. A *finely divided* tool will have a lot of scale markings. The most precise types of scale were [*Vernier scales*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vernier_scale). Now that more and more tools are digital in nature, it may make more sense to talk about *increments*, rather than *divisions*.

Comment: This would also apply to cutting tools as well as to measuring tools. A lathe with a fine thread on the feed shaft would be more accurate than one with a course thread. Each turn of the shaft would move the carriage through a smaller _increment_ wouldn't it?

Comment: That's true. The [*indexing heads*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexing_head) used on lathes to cut gear teeth are also known as *dividing heads* (or just *dividers*).

Answer (score 0):

"*Finely incremented* tools" could also be understood as "having *more accuracy*."

In this case the word "finely" is used to distinguish the tools from tools of lesser quality (presumed to have less capacity for measurement).